# Should data be centered+scaled before applying t-SNE?

Tags: normalization, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional, tsne

Some of my data's features have large values, while other features have much smaller values.

Is it necessary to center+scale data before applying t-SNE to prevent bias towards the larger values?

I use Python's sklearn.manifold.TSNE implementation with the default euclidean distance metric.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Centering shouldn't matter since the algorithm only operates on distances between points, however rescaling is necessary if you want the different dimensions to be treated with equal importance, since the 2-norm will be more heavily influenced by dimensions with large variance.

Comment: By "rescaling" do you mean Min-Max scaling or Standardization?

Comment: Standardization